# continue color scale is not working in ggplot2_2.0.0 in windows remote desktop

Tags: r, ggplot2

it seems continue color scale is not working in the latest version of ggplot2 (2.0.0) when I use window remote desktop (Window 7 SP1 enterprise)

This is my test code:

```
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(cars) +
    geom_point(aes(speed, speed, colour = dist))
```

The figure doesn't show the color bar in  the legend.

[image]

The same code is working on local windows laptop and remote Linux server.

Any suggestion to fix this problem.

My session info

```
R version 3.2.2 (2015-08-14)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
Running under: Windows 7 x64 (build 7601) Service Pack 1

locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=English_Australia.1252  LC_CTYPE=English_Australia.1252    LC_MONETARY=English_Australia.1252
[4] LC_NUMERIC=C                       LC_TIME=English_Australia.1252    

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
[1] ggplot2_2.0.0

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
 [1] labeling_0.3     colorspace_1.2-6 scales_0.3.0     plyr_1.8.3       tools_3.2.2      gtable_0.1.2    
 [7] Rcpp_0.12.3      grid_3.2.2       digest_0.6.9     munsell_0.4.2
```

Comment: And any reason for not using R 3.2.3, the latest version?

Comment: Sorry it is a typo. Should be 2.0.0. No specific reason for 3.2.3. All my computers used the same version of R.

Comment: @MikeWise Thanks for your suggestions. It is duplicate with your link which do solve my problem. I adjust  the color depth to 32 bit then everything is working now.

Comment: You are welcome. Too bad, was hoping for more progress on my ggplot2 badge, but I can hardly submit an answer for such a simple duplicate :)

Comment: You could submit your own answer and mark it correct, so it doesn't stay open.